# Is it normal for minted to run slow?

Tags: minted, code, highlighting, latexmk

I just install minted, but the simple command:

```
latexmk -pdf -shell-escape main.tex
```

with main.tex simply being:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{r}
sprem <- choose(13, 2)
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

takes about 5 seconds. Can anything be done to make it faster?

Comment: Might be useful to know which OS you are using? On my Linux box your example took about 1.1s

Comment: @daleif I am using Windows with miktex latex installed.

Comment: That might explain it, `latexmk` is written in perl, and it is a slow starter on windows, which might explain the extra time. Besides 5s is nothing.

Comment: Minted uses caching, so if you run the same example again it should be faster than the first time (obviously if you change the code fragment or add more fragments then minted needs to run again). However as commented above the real problem may be Latexmk. You could try running just `pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex`, that should be faster as well.

Comment: There are two main problems: (a) pdflatex is slow with minted, especially with its running of external programs.  (b) latexmk does an extra unnecessary run of pdflatex, because it sees that the aux file was changed.  The change is for cache information for minted, but latexmk doesn't know it won't affect the pdf file. The overhead for latexmk is relatively small. Note that the time does **not** go up proportionally for big documents.  Problem (a) can't be avoided, but there should be a solution to the extra run issue; I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Minted itself does run slow, at least in part because of the external programs it runs, especially pygmentize. But latexmk compounds the problem by sometimes running pdflatex one more time than needed, as with this document.  The extra run of pdflatex for the simple document is because after the first run, minted puts cached information in the .aux file. Latexmk sees the changed .aux file, but doesn't know that the changes won't matter for the contents of the .pdf file.  See below for how to educate latexmk.

On my (rather old) iMac with macOS and TeXLive 2021, the processing time with latexmk is about 3.5 sec.  This is 1.7 sec and 1.4 sec for the two runs of pdflatex and 0.4 sec overhead in latexmk.  But these times don't scale up to astronomical times for a realistic larger document; e.g., the minted documentation (91 pages) took about 23 sec to process using latexmk.

To solve the problem of the extra run of pdflatex, put the following in one of the latexmkrc files:

```
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{aux} = 'minted@oldcachelist|default\.pygstyle|\.pygtex';
```

This tells latexmk that when it examines the .aux file for changes it is to ignore the lines that minted writes for its cache information.  (Experts can improve the above regular expression, but it would be longer and harder to understand.)